# using standard input in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I always run my shell with a command:

```
./shellName file1 file2
```

So, in the shell, I can refer file1 as $1 and file2 as $2. However, if I want to run the shell with this command

```
./shellName < file1 > file2
```

I tried to read the file1 as standard input and file 2 as standard output. How can I refer file1 and file2 in the shell script? Can I still use $1 and $2?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# read from file1
read LINE

# write to file2 line we just readed
echo $LINE
```

Comment: do you mean, in the script I can refer file1 as LINE?

Comment: no, `LINE` is a name of variable you read to, since you have replaced `stdin` with file input - you don't have to use any specific name to refer to input file, you just read it line by line

Comment: so, previously I used filename in the sed command : sed -i 's/somePattern/replacedPattern/g' $2. How can I change this command with LINE?

Comment: echo $LINE | sed 's/somePattern/replacedPattern/g'

Comment: okay. I got it. However, what should I do if I am going to make several changes before I write it to the output file? should I make an temp file? if so, how can I make an temp file in shell?

Comment: just don't `echo` the line before you do all your modifications, or you can chain your commands like `echo $LINE | sed s/foo/bar/ | sed s/xxx/yyy/ | tr -d XYZ`

Answer (score 1):

Any `read` statement in your script will read from file1 and any `echo/print` statement will write the output to file2. `$1` and `$2` will be empty

Answer (score 0):

If you directing files in, I don't think that the script has the variables available to them, rather the text is read from file1 and used as input for the script and anything outputted will end up in file2